# Magento2 new customer assignment to group for Valid VAT ID doesn't seem to work

Tags: magento2, customer-group, vat

As I understood, enabling in 'Stores > Configuration > Customer configuration > Create new account options' the assignment to a customer group according to valid/invalid Vat ID should suffice to the proper customer handling *on registration*.

As for now, it is not working, so I am forced to do that manually for each new customer.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the assignment with european VAT's it wont work cause in europe is the countrycode also in the VAT (eg. ATUXXXXXX, DEXXXXXX).

I wrote a [module](https://github.com/CopeX/CopeX_VatFix) to fix this.

Comment: I tried registring with a valid italian VAT ID in the format IT**********, but the customer is still put in the default customer group.

Comment: Regarding your module, it breaks magento, but I didn't investigate further on the issue, I just removed it. Here's the output when i run setup:upgrade http://imgur.com/NNO70Zx

Comment: which version of Magento2 do you use ? 
see here for official documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/create_component.html#module-xml

Comment: Magento 2.0.6. I don't know, it boggles me. I need to look more into it

Comment: this happened because of some "old" spelling in xml's its fixed now.